# Issue while exporting from jsp to excel xlsx format

Tags: excel, jsp

I have 2 JSPs named:

1. userDetails.jsp
2. exportUser.jsp

First JSP will display database records in a table. Below the table a link named "Export to Excel" is available:

```
  <a href="exportUser.jsp"> Export to Excel</a>
```

Once the link is clicked, I need to export data to excel .xlsx format via exportUser.jsp

Both JSPs will have similar code except the second JSP has

```
 <%@page contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

However, I get this error from Excel:

> Excel cannot open the file 'exportUser.jsp' because the file format or
>   file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been
>   corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Comment: If the JSP page having the same data from DataBase, why are you trying to export from JSP? See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277967/exporting-database-query-results-to-excel-using-apache-poi) for how to export from database to excel sheet using java.

Comment: client want the excel on his system instead of downloading from server"s temp folder.